# How to get the coordinates of the dots in AreaChart of Rechart?

Tags: reactjs, charts, recharts

I am trying to customize the tooltip of AreaChart of ReCharts. The tooltip component is fully customizable, but I am struggling with the position of the tooltip, I want to position the tooltip just above where the dot meet the grid lines.

I want to do something like this
[image: I want to do something like this]

But this is what it is like currently, the tooltip moves on moving my mouse over y-axis
[image: This is not what I want]